# Typescript mapped interfaces

Tags: typescript

I have this interface:

```
interface Events {
  SERVER_START: {
    version: string;
  };
  SERVER_READY: {
    host: string;
    port: number;
  };
  SERVER_STOP: undefined;
  SERVER_STOP_ERROR: {
    error: Error;
  };
  SERVER_CONNECTION_INCOMING: {
    clientId: string;
    address: string;
    port: number;
  };
 ...
}
```

is it possible to map functions parameters like this?

```
function logEvent(type: keyof Events, data?: Events[keyof Events]): void;
```

This work *almost* fine, since I can call `logEvent` like this:

```
// this is correct:
logEvent('SERVER_START', { version: '0.1.0' });

// but this is also correct, which shouldn't
logEvent('SERVER_START');
logEvent('SERVER_START', { host, port });
```

Of course, intellisense also don't work as expected so, I had to manually define all the overloadings of the function like...

```
function logEvent(type: 'SERVER_START', data: Events['SERVER_START']): void;
function logEvent(type: 'SERVER_READY', data: Events['SERVER_READY']): void;
function logEvent(type: 'SERVER_STOP'): void;
...
```

which works like a charm, but it looks to me like there should be a better way to define all of this automagically...

**Update:**

So, the idea is not having only `Events` but extending that interface with other definitions as well, so the idea would be to have a generic function like

```
function logEvent<E extends Events>(type: keyof E, data?: E[keyof E]): void;
```

so you can actually do

```
interface MoreEvents extends Events {
  FOOBAR: {
    foo: string;
    bar: number;
  };
}

// call it with the original ones
logEvent('SERVER_START', { version: '0.1.0' });

// call it also with the new events
logEvent<MoreEvents>('FOOBAR', { foo, bar });
```

but with proper type checking

Answer (score 1):

You can redefine your `logEvent` function using generics

```
logEvent<E extends Events>(type: keyof E, data?: E[keyof E]): void;
```

**Update**

This solution works with the updated question. Check [that playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKIDcLgM7IN4BQyyAyqgEoBqFA+iQCoCC59AXPkccplNsAPYh22MFFABzANycAvtOJkqtcqkYARAJrtCXZAAt+I4aInyuAB35Qw7EAFcAtgCNoZuZ0XVydegHkACux2IAAmEDCgECFmnrQMATQU5L7k2pzE0FBW7KhQWVBuMRReNADCvgByFail9ACSlTR1FeUAss0A4mm6CAA2wFhgdSHGYiBS6chwISFQENjYo6aTlta2ji4FstIyBASgkLCIKK1WEBiDuBAAHpChuBc4HMQAYr6+AELM3Vww-PxLcZmYhOOBQdbOVzbAi7AgAejhyBgwQQYAEIGQvX44keYAAFGAAJ7mCDsADWEEJ-BgaEwOAANMgQnAwHAAPw5OlgbAAbQpVJpuOwAF0AJTsdD8YDRAjIkCo9GY7G4gA8qGQNzuIQeXOwAD4CcTSch+dS0IzmayOWg+ZSzagxfhiHt3PDEQg4L1eshgGBkAB3X16ZBgPQoKzAcSgT3IQTzAhYnFcvEAcli3gYzHoKcZeG40D4gnYKYADAA6ACMZZLKeQMlF0jdyA9Xp9fs92H4AaDIbDyBAEH9Gt1CeVXJVpzmQoNKben2YOadfwByBTi9B4OQFYATABmOsN0dJwYTs7T1Nzr7kRd55fF9dg4s73e1+vSIA)

Comment: omg so stupid solution... I tried lots of them but didn't get the correct syntax. Thanks this works. By the way, making the second parameter optional works just fine too :)

Comment: Happy to help. I was not sure about the second argument

Comment: wait, if `T` extends `keyof Events` that means that, there could be some values which will `Events[T]` will be `undefined`, right? So that's not really valid...

Comment: To answer your comment if you have `logEvent<T extends keyof Events>` then `T` will always be one of the key of `Events`, so no undefined

Comment: It also works with the updated question, check the playground in the updated answer